# unable to map array of objects with key indicator

Tags: reactjs, arrays, object, next.js, array.prototype.map

please check the screenshot how can we map array of objects.

```
{posts.map((post) => {
            <PostList
              id={post.id}
              key={post.id}
              username={post?.data?.username}
              profileImage={post?.data?.profileImage}
              postImage={post?.data?.postImage}
              description={post?.data?.description}
            />;
          })}
```

[image]

Comment: have you tried using the index as the key? as in `posts.map((post, index) => {<PostList id={post.id} key={index} ..../>})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.map` function is not `return`ing anything

```
{posts.map((post) => { // Open new scope
  // Nothing being returned here
  <PostList
    id={post.id}
    key={post.id}
    username={post?.data?.username}
    profileImage={post?.data?.profileImage}
    postImage={post?.data?.postImage}
    description={post?.data?.description}
  />;
})}
```

You can solve this in two ways

1: directly returning the `<PostList>` with an implicit return

```
{posts.map((post) => ( // Implicit return
  <PostList
    id={post.id}
    key={post.id}
    username={post?.data?.username}
    profileImage={post?.data?.profileImage}
    postImage={post?.data?.postImage}
    description={post?.data?.description}
  />
))}
```

or 2. using an explicit `return`

```
{posts.map((post) => { // Open new scope
  // We can do stuff here
  // Like a console.log(post)
  return ( // Explicit return
    <PostList
      id={post.id}
      key={post.id}
      username={post?.data?.username}
      profileImage={post?.data?.profileImage}
      postImage={post?.data?.postImage}
      description={post?.data?.description}
    />
  )
})}
```

Answer (score 0):

what is your problem exactly? The codes looks good the change I think you made in your code is to return the component inside the map like this

```
{posts.map((post) => {
       return (
            <PostList
              id={post.id}
              key={post.id}
              username={post?.data?.username}
              profileImage={post?.data?.profileImage}
              postImage={post?.data?.postImage}
              description={post?.data?.description}
            />;
    )
  })}
```